# Message is different in different browser

Tags: jquery

I wrote a code which will show a message if any one tries to leave the page.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   return "You haven't finished your post yet. Do you want to leave without finishing.";
});

$('form#EditProposalForm').submit(function() {
   $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

It works perfectly. But It shows different message with different browser like mozilla and crome shows different output. What should i do in this purpose??
Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes